# random current on/off IC available?

Tags: integrated-circuit, random

I am still very new to electronics, but have been using Arduino to build stuff with.  But I require a component for a project that does not contain any Arduino because of space.

So I am looking to see if there is, or the best work-around, a IC that will randomly generate a pulse if a button is pressed.  So once the button is pressed it either allows a pulse to go though to an I/O, or stops it.  But for this to be random.

The space is width 150mm and length 500mm and a 7mm height. it only has a small current as the battery is 3v.

Any ideas/advice to achieve this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What about possibly each and every microcontroller on the market?

Comment: Arduino comes in many forms and sizes. Have a look at an Arduino mini, or pro mini which are much smaller than an Arduino Uno. If you want smaller still use a PIC microcontroller chip. Getting the **random** behavior without a microcontroller will be a challenge, especially for a newbee like you. Also you will **NOT** be able to make anything smaller than a PIC microcontroller in an 8-pins DIP package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny85) is the ATtiny85. It comes in sizes from small to very, very small.

[This](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) is an Arduino core that works with the ATtiny85.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this.  With what you have above, I would buy a ATtiny85 and use a USB serial to load the Arduino core, and then use Arduino software to code the random function?

Comment: No, the Arduino core gets integrated with the Arduino IDE, and then you use a USB AVR programmer to program it.

Comment: Would a USB to TTL driver do the same thing, and allow me to code it ?

Comment: A basic USB-UART bridge will not suffice. You might be able to use ArduinoISP, but I cannot vouch for its success.

Comment: OKay, seems a good idea to invest in a AVR programmer then.  Thank you, I will give it ago.

Comment: Could I ask for some advice on this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Programmer-USB-AVRISP-XPII-Compatible/dp/B00KM6ZA9I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1508838658&sr=8-1&keywords=USB+AVR+programmer[/link]

Comment: Waveshare is reputable, and that programmer should do you.

Comment: It's so weird seing [that chip](http://www.microchip.com/_images/ics/medium-ATtiny85-PDIP-8.png) labeled with "Microchip ATtiny85"...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a pair of NOT gates along with a pair of P-channel MOSFETs.

[image]

This is a random-bit generator. Switching transistors off forces the inputs and outputs of both inverters to the logical high state (a logical high could be 3.3V, for instance). An inverter is an element whose output is opposite of its input. But here the internal circuitry of inverters have to modify in such a way to let both inputs and outputs change to the logical high state! This is odd but it happens.

Now when a logical high signal comes into the gates these transistors are turned off. But since inverters don't like having all their inputs and outputs in the same state, the circuit in a small fraction of time picks a random output at node A. Once node A is determined the node B will also be known. The reason that the final state is random is due to the thermal noise exists inside the inverters which determines the outcome of this circuit.

We know that no two inverters are exactly the same, but in this application, the differences do not affect the randomness of the circuit. I haven't yet tried this circuit but I guess it works.